# Assigning UIImage to Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView inside TableViewController. The collection view cells are there for displaying photos of users. However, what I am fetching from database is the url path.

I am also planning to manipulate more on the images data, thus I chose to store them in an array `profileImages` (but I am not sure if I should use as array of NSURL)..

*(I am also using Firebase as backend which lively listens for the changes, that's why I setup the `isIndexValid` check part)*

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

   var profileImages = [NSURL]()

   // Database Checks Hits into `retrievePhotos()`

   func retrieveUserPhotos(user: AnyObject) {
    if let profilePicLink = user["firstImage"]! {
        let firstImagePath = profilePicLink as! String

        if let fileUrl = NSURL(string: firstImagePath) {
            print(fileUrl)
            let isIndexValid = profileImages.indices.contains(0)

            if (!isIndexValid) {
                profileImages.append(fileUrl)
                print(profileImages)
            } else {
                profileImages[0] = fileUrl
            }
        }
     }
   }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
```

---

Until now everyhing works nice. I am fetching the image url successfully now.

But at this point, I got confused on assign the image to UIImage in cell. (I tried using it with Heneke as it seemed easier).

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    // below returns fatal error `Index out of range`
    cell.currentImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(profileImages[indexPath.row])


    // Also tried this but it doesn't update the UIImage. 
   // I guess it's because it's already loaded once without download of the images from the link get completed:
    if profileImages.count > 0 {
      cell.currentImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(profileImages[indexPath.row])
    }

    return cell

}
```

What is the proper way of handling fetching images and assigning to collection view cell's UIImage?

Comment: I updated my question. If I do the check in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, the image never gets updated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920632/how-to-asynchronously-load-uitableviewcell-images-so-that-scrolling-doesnt-lag or https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/ or https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html should get you on your way

Comment: The answer was `collectionView.reloadData()` afterwards.. After tweaking a bit more, I understand the nature of it. Thanks

Comment: You should look into reloadRowsAtIndexPaths instead of reloadData(). You don't want to reload the entire view every time an async operation is finished

Comment: @Moonwalkr Can you please show an example as an answer on how to implement it? And I can accept your answer. Does collectionView has `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`?

Comment: Sorry, for collectionview it's reloadItemsAtIndexPaths. I'll provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where to call the `reloadItemAtIndexPaths` depends on how you're solving the async operations now. Your async operation should be called for every image you are downloading, so that you can update the corresponding row whenever the image for that row has been fetched. In the callback or whatever for that operation, you call

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(myArrayOfIndexPaths)
```

`myArrayOfIndexPaths` would then contain only 1 item, which is the indexPath for the current row. So, you would have an async fetch method which you call with the current indexPath as a parameter. You add this to an empty `myArrayOfIndexPaths`, and then you call reload.

Comment: First, I tried putting `collectionView.reloadData()` inside `retrieveUserPhotos()`at the bottom. It was working okay but your comment above encouraged me to adapt it. However, now I tried to change it to `collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(profileImages)`, but I couldn't figure out what to put inside the pharantesis..

Comment: if your 'retrieveUserPhotos' is retrieving ALL photos, then you're not really updating the rows as soon as each photo is ready. You're then fetching ALL photos async and then reloading. In this case, it's better to use reloadData(). HOWEVER: this is not a good solution, as you're fetching all photos even though that might be (probably is?) more photos than you are currently showing. If the user had 500 photos, then you're fetching ALL those photos before reloading the view. Very inefficient. That's why you should have a func that is called for each row as it is being displayed